# How to call list view in another class and then clear it

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

We want to call list view 'm_vwList' in another class, so that when check out button (in another class) is pressed, the list is cleared from Quick Order Class.

Can someone pls tell how to call the list view in another class and then clear it after clicking the button. we know the button functionality but not sure of how to clear the list

```
    package com.zing.basket;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    /**
      * Created by Student on 18/03/2016.
      */
     public class QuickOrder  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener {

    private EditText m_vwEditText;
    private Button m_vwButton;
    private ListView m_vwList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;

    View myFragmentView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quickorder, container, false);


        m_vwEditText = (EditText) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        m_vwButton = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        m_vwList = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.textview);
        String[] listItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listitems);
        for (String item : listItems) {
            m_adapter.add(item);
        }
        m_vwList.setAdapter(m_adapter);

        m_vwButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        m_vwEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);


        return myFragmentView;
    }



    /** Called when the Button is clicked */

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String item = m_vwEditText.getText().toString();
        m_vwEditText.setText("");
        if (!item.equals("")) m_adapter.add(item);
    }

    /** Called whena key is pressed while the EditText view has focus */

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String item = m_vwEditText.getText().toString();
                m_vwEditText.setText("");
                if (!item.equals("")) m_adapter.add(item);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: QuickOrder is a Fragment right?  your list view in QuickOrder  fragment right? and from where u want to call this list view??

Comment: if your list view in this fragment then create the instance of this fragment QuickOrder  fragInstance = new QuickOrder  (); fragInstance.m_vwList.inValidateViews();

Answer (score 3):

To call `ListView` of a different class, you need to get instance of that class and check it's null or not. Fore more look at:

```
  if (MainActivity.getInstance() != null) {
     MainActivity.getInstance().mDrawerList.invalidateViews();
     }
```

Comment: would this be same for a fragment? my code is in a fragment actually

Comment: Where is the `ListView`?

Comment: in the above mentioned class. which is actually a fragment

Comment: alright. Create instance of that fragment and call ListView.